# Magento 2 Default form validation

Tags: magento2, validation

How can i add pattern="[0-9]*" validation in my login form ?

Comment: Do you mean customer login form?

Comment: Yes as per my case i have add pattern to allow number only

Comment: From where you add pattern can you share your code?

Comment: i have add in simple html

Comment: <input name="login[username]" value="" inputmode="numeric" pattern="[0-9]*" autocomplete="off" id="email" type="text" title="Email" data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-phoneStrict':true}" placeholder="(123) 456-7890" maxlength="14">

Comment: if i have add this type then password field validation is not working so i just ask you proper method for add pattern validation

Comment: You can not add pattern like this for that you have to go with JS validation.

Comment: Check my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87586/discussion-between-chirag-patel-and-sam).

Answer (score 1):

Try below way.

> app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/Magento_Customer/templates/form/login.phtml

Find the line `data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-password':true}"`

And replace with `data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-mycustom-password':true}"`

Add the following code at the end of the file.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
require([
    'jquery',
    'jquery/ui',
    'jquery/validate',
    'mage/translate'
], function($){
    $.validator.addMethod(
    'validate-mycustom-password', function (value) { 
    return (value.length == 6 && /^-?\d+$/.test(value));
    }, $.mage.__('Password length should be 6 and only numbers are allowed'));
});
```

Don't forgot to run necessary command like `static:content:deploy` & `cache:flush`

**Note:** I give a validation for Max limit & allow only number. you have to customize script as per your requirement.